# Retrofit get call to get a model with a list of an other model not working

Tags: android, api, android-studio, retrofit

I have an Api call in android that gave me an observableList of Frame but the problem is that in my model I want to have a list of an other model but that is not working. Can somebody help me with how i need to do that because i can't find it.

Below you find how the get is in postman

```
[
    {
        "FrameId": 4,
        "DurationFrame": 0,
        "PointsWinner": 0,
        "PointsOpponent": 0,
        "Winner": "",
        "MatchId": 58,
        "Breaks": [
            {
                "BreakId": 2,
                "Player": "Dennis",
                "MomentPlayed": "2018-12-30T13:05:08.223",
                "NumberPoints": 30,
                "Opponent": "Danny",
                "TypeBreak": "Match",
                "FrameId": 4
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "FrameId": 5,
        "DurationFrame": 0,
        "PointsWinner": 0,
        "PointsOpponent": 0,
        "Winner": "",
        "MatchId": 58,
        "Breaks": []
    }
]
```

Below you find the model class of frame

```
class Frame:Serializable {
    @field:Json(name = "FrameId")
    var frameId: Int = 0
    @field:Json(name = "DurationFrame")
    var durationFrame: Double = 0.0
    @field:Json(name = "PointsWinner")
    var pointsWinner: Int = 0
    @field:Json(name = "PointsOpponent")
    var pointsOpponent: Int = 0
    @field:Json(name = "Winner")
    var winner: String = ""
    @field:Json(name = "MatchId")
    var matchId: Int? = 0
    var breaks: List<Breaks> = null


    constructor() {}

    constructor(frameId: Int, durationFrame: Double, pointsWinner: Int,     pointsOpponent: Int, winner: String, matchId: Int) {
        this.frameId = frameId
        this.durationFrame = durationFrame
        this.pointsWinner = pointsWinner
        this.pointsOpponent = pointsOpponent
        this.winner = winner
        this.matchId = matchId

    }
}
```

Below you find the api call

```
@GET("api/Frames/matchid/{matchid}")
fun getFramesForMatchId(@Path("matchid") matchid : Int): Observable<List<Frame>>
```

The call that i do is to get all the frames of a specific match

Comment: What you mean - not working? You get null? Have you tried annotating var breaks with @field:Json(name = "Breaks") ?

Comment: That was the problem thank you sorry stupid from me

Comment: Ok, adding this as an answer so it is better noticeable for future post visitors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your field name "breaks" mismatches the json parameter name "Breaks", you must add appropriate annotation:

```
...
@field:Json(name = "Breaks")
var breaks: List<Breaks> = null
...
```